# How do I run an iPad Simulator in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, ipad, ios-simulator

I am trying to run an iPad simulator on Xcode, but currently I only have one option when I go to Xcode > Open Developer Tool > Simulator, which launches the iPhone simulator.

How do I launch the iPad simulator?

Comment: Look in the devices and simulators window, under simulators. Have you installed any iPad simulators? If so, pick one as you set the destination for running the project. If not, do that first.

Comment: In Xcode, try
"Product" > "Destination" > "iPad Pro (..)"

Answer (score 19):

You should select an iPad device by navigating to

**Hardware/Device/[OS version if you have multiple OS versions installed]/[device]**

in the simulator's menu.

[image: Hardware/Device/[OS version if you have multiple OS versions installed]/[device]]

If there are no iPad devices in the list, follow these instructions:

1. Click on **Hardware/Device/Manage Devices...**

   [image: Hardware/Device/Manage Devices...]
2. Select the **Simulators** option on the top.

   [image: "Simulators" option selected]
3. Press the plus (**+**) sign in the lower-left corner.

   [image: Plus sign in the lower-left corner]
4. Define the name, the device type and the OS version of the new simulator, then click on **Create**.

   [image: Options for the new simulator]

For more information, check out [Getting started in Simulator](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/GettingStartedwithiOSSimulator/GettingStartedwithiOSSimulator.html).

Answer (score 14):

This is for Xcode 11.2.1+

Open XCode from the App menu:

Xcode -> Open Developer Tool -> Simulator

[image]

This will open the latest iPhone simulator, and to change it to anything else, e.g., iPad:

Hardware -> Device -> iOS -> iPad

[image]

Comment: Thanks, your answer is awesome and the newest version.

Answer (score 13):

This has changed.
Now, after you opened your simulator as you mentioned you need in the simulator menu bar to go to:
File -> Open Simulator -> [ios version] -> [ios device]
There you can find an ipad simulator to open.

Comment: Thanks Man. This shall be the right answer.

Answer (score 7):

For bonus points :)

I would also extract the simulator from inside Xcode to make it more accessible.

`Applications / Xcode.app` ( right click and select "Show Package Contents" )

From this folder `Contents / Developer / Applications / Simulator.app`

Create a shortcut to that and simulator opens without opening the main Xcode.app

Answer (score 2):

Open Simulator, go to File > Open Simulator > {Your version of IOS} > {Device you want}.

Dont Forget to rebuild your app before trying to launch it.